# Getting rid of undesired layout element on webpage

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser, stylesheet

What's this?

[image]

And how do I get rid of it? [Actual webpage here](http://www.glamourunderground.com/how-to-start-running/).

Comment: Which browser is that screenshot from?  'Cause I don't see it.

Comment: I see it in Chrome 11 on OS X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `min-width: 640px` from your `.singleinfo` css class

Answer (score 4):

The min-width for the `singleinfo` class is set to `640px` while the backgroundimage is only 630px wide. You can set no-repeat on the background or change the `min-width` to `630px`.

Answer (score 3):

It's the background of `div.singleinfo` repeating. To get rid of it, add `no-repeat` to the `background` property, so it becomes:

```
background: #F7F7F7 url(images/macmet.jpg) bottom left no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from defaulting to a repeating background, you've also set the background colour inconsistent with the remainder of the page.

```
.singleinfo { background: #F4F4F4 url(images/macmet.jpg) bottom left no-repeat; }
```

Appears correctly in Chrome 11 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Change your **style.css** to get this:

```
.singleinfo {
    background: url("images/macmet.jpg") no-repeat scroll left bottom #F4F4F4;
    font: 12px Georgia,Arial,century gothic,verdana,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 20px;
    min-width: 640px;
    padding: 5px 0 15px;
}
```

This fix was tested and works OK on:

- **Mozilla Firefox 4**.0.1
- **Internet Explorer 9**.0.8112.16421
- **Opera 11.10**.2092
- **Google Chrome 11**.0.696.60

[image: use firebug]

Answer (score 1):

change the `background` property of your class  `.singleinfo` to >

`background: url("images/macmet.jpg") no-repeat scroll left bottom #F7F7F7`